# Super Search DB error with Matrix fields

Tags: matrix, database, solspace, supersearch, database-error

I want to re-hash this issue: http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/17419/

The error is:

```
Error Number: 1052

Column 'field_id_90' in field list is ambiguous
```

It seems there was never a proper solution and I'm having the same issue. I can confirm (at least in my testing) that the issue is related to Matrix fields given a relevant value in Super Search.

I’m running EE 2.7.2, SS 2.1.3 and Matrix 2.5.8.

My two matrix fields are: `services_about` & `ct_sub_sections`

**this works:**

```
relevance=“title=1+services_tags=5+ct_tags=5+page_keywords=5+services_introduction=2+ct_about=1+body=1+count_words_within_words”
```

**this doesn’t:**

```
relevance=“title=1+services_tags=5+ct_tags=5+page_keywords=5+services_introduction=2+services_about =1+ct_about=1+ct_sub_sections=1+body=1+count_words_within_words”
```

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the search index in Super Search? You can do that from CP => Add-Ons => Modules => Super Search => Utilities. You could also clear the cache in the Preferences section.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Column 'field_id_43' in field list is ambiguous. SELECT t.entry_id, t.title, field_id_9 AS `cf-pages-heading`, field_id_10 AS `cf-pages-subheading`, field_id_4 AS `cf-pages-intro`, field_id_5 AS `cf-pages-leftcol`, field_id_7 AS `cf-pages-rightcol`, field_id_8 AS `cf-pages-bottom-col-wide`, field_id_12 AS `cf-news-heading`, field_id_13 AS `cf-news-subheading`, field_id_14 AS `cf-news-excerpt`, field_id_15 AS `cf-news-content`, field_id_18 AS `cf-news-url`, field_id_19 AS `cf-toolkit-heading`, field_id_20 AS `cf-toolkit-subheading`, field_id_26 AS `cf-toolkit-intro`

Answer (score 2):

I am experiencing the same problem where it seems to happen when "Is field searchable?" is enabled within the field settings containing the Matrix field-type (not sure why??!)...

I found a solution by changing line 7595 from

```
$select .= ', field_id_'.$fields[$key].' AS `'.$key.'`';
```

to

```
$select .= ', cd.field_id_'.$fields[$key].' AS `'.$key.'`';
```

Within mod.super_search.php. This seems to have fixed the problem where the table alias is added to the field.

Super Search V2.1.3

Comment: Seemed to work but I don't want to mark this as answered because it requires hacking the add-on. Can anyone from @solspace confirm?

Comment: This is a correct solution, and it'll be available in the next version of Super Search :)